# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 26 path $.result

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

5Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 26 path $.resultExpected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 26 path $.resultExpected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 26 path $.result Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 26 path $.result

Answer (score 1):

From your logcat, your API is sending:

```
{"kode":"true","result":"Data ditemukan!"}
```

While your model in android has:

```
@SerializedName("kode")
String kode;

@SerializedName("result")
List<DataModel> result;
```

Your model expects "result" to be a list of Datamodel object, while your api returns a string, you need to either change the type of your "result" in android to be String, or to make sure your php is actually sending an array of object as "result", depending on what you need.

More generally, when you see a line like this one

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 26 path $.result

It means that the gson converter failed to match what you got from you call to the model. Here, it means at some point he was expecting an array (expected BEGIN_ARRAY) but found something else instead, here a string.
If you look at the line that your API sent, which is

```
{"kode":"true","result":"Data ditemukan!"}
```

You see that column 26 is actually the " character of the "Data ditemukan!" string, and that's how you can know that this is the conversion of "result" field that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your android code has no problem the PHP webservice returns in List.

so

> Either you can replace this code in your PHP file

```
  ->set_content_type('application/json')
  ->set_output(json_encode('kode'=>$kode,'result'=> $result));
```

> or you have to take List in retrofit like this

```
@GET("kartu/{NoKartu}/{Pin}/{Hp}")
    Call<List<ResponsModel>> kartuu (@Path("NoKartu") String nokar,
                                    @Path("Pin") String pin,
                                    @Path("Hp") String hp);
```

Comment: it can't be run the results are still error, but I've found the solution ... thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

Response issued when request "192.168.1.14/tesemaal/api/data/kartu/{NoKartu}/{Pin}/{Hp}" how? Can it be shown? It could be that your mistake is only in pojo.